# Date format of cell in excel OpenXml

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, openxml-sdk

i creating excel file through OpenXML SDK 2.5. I have IDIsposable class which includesa variable

```
private SpreadsheetDocument ProcessDocument { get; set; }
```

I can insert a cell with date value:

```
var cell = GetCell(sheet, columnName, rowIndex); //method return a cell

cell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.Number);
cell.CellValue = new CellValue(dateResult.ToOADate().ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
cell.StyleIndex = 0;
```

In this state when I open a created excel file in cell i see a number. that is OK, i mean, but now i need to set a cell format... I have a methods:

```
public virtual UInt32 CreateCellFormat(String format)
{
    NumberingFormat nf = new NumberingFormat();
    nf.FormatCode = format;

    if (this.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.NumberingFormats == null)
    {
        this.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.NumberingFormats = new NumberingFormats();
        this.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.NumberingFormats.AppendChild(new NumberingFormats(new NumberingFormat() { NumberFormatId = 0 }));
        this.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.NumberingFormats.Count = 1;
    }

    var numberFormatId = this.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.NumberingFormats.Elements<NumberingFormat>().Where(a => a.NumberFormatId.HasValue).Select(a => a.NumberFormatId).Max();
    nf.NumberFormatId =  numberFormatId == null || numberFormatId < 199 ? 200 : numberFormatId + 1;

    this.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.NumberingFormats.InsertAt(nf, (int)this.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.NumberingFormats.Count.Value);
    this.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.NumberingFormats.Count++;

    return nf.NumberFormatId;
}
public virtual void SetCellStyle(Sheet sheet, UInt32 rowIndex, String columnName, UInt32? fontIndex, UInt32? fillIndex, UInt32? formatIndex)
{
    var cell1 = this.GetCell(sheet, columnName, rowIndex);
    cell1.StyleIndex = this.CreateCellFormat(sheet, fontIndex, fillIndex, formatIndex);
}

internal virtual UInt32 CreateCellFormat(Sheet sheet, UInt32? fontIndex, UInt32? fillIndex, UInt32? formatIndex)
{
    CellFormat cellFormat = new CellFormat();
    WorksheetPart workSheetPart = this.GetWorkSheetPart(sheet.Name);

    if (fontIndex.HasValue)
    {
        cellFormat.FontId = fontIndex;
        cellFormat.ApplyFont = true;
    }

    if (fillIndex.HasValue)
    {
        cellFormat.FillId = fillIndex;
        cellFormat.ApplyFill = true;
    }

    if (formatIndex.HasValue)
    {
        cellFormat.NumberFormatId = formatIndex;

        cellFormat.ApplyNumberFormat = BooleanValue.FromBoolean(true);
    }

    if (this.ProcessDocument.WorkbookPart.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.CellFormats == null)
    {
        this.ProcessDocument.WorkbookPart.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.CellFormats = new CellFormats();
        this.ProcessDocument.WorkbookPart.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.CellFormats.Append(new CellFormat());
        this.ProcessDocument.WorkbookPart.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.CellFormats.Count = 1;
    }

    this.ProcessDocument.WorkbookPart.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.CellFormats.InsertAt(cellFormat, 
        (int)this.ProcessDocument.WorkbookPart.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.CellFormats.Count.Value);

    UInt32 result = this.ProcessDocument.WorkbookPart.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.CellFormats.Count;
    this.ProcessDocument.WorkbookPart.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.CellFormats.Count++;

    return result;

}
```

In creating process i used it:

```
var formatIndex = excel.CreateCellFormat("dd.mm.yyyy");
excel.AddCellValue(workSheet, row, 6, DateTime.Now);
excel.SetCellStyle(workSheet, row, 6, null, null, formatIndex);
```

At this moment, when I open the generated excel, I receive this message: *“Excel found unreadable content in 'test.xlsx'. Do you want to recover the contents of this workbook? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes.”*

After repairing my excel report an error in the file **"/xl/styles.xml"**.

Does anyone know where I make a mistake in creating the format of the cell?
Thanks a lot

Comment: not familiar with OpenXML but is there no `.NumberFormat` property on cells? Ie. `cell1..NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"` ?

Comment: No, this option is not there.
but i have found a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11116176/cell-styles-in-openxml-spreadsheet-spreadsheetml

Comment: Answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30661509/907903