# Repaired Records: Format from /xl/styles.xml part (Styles) , I don't get this issue? help me fixing it... thanx in advance

Tags: c#

Likely similar post [Cell styles in OpenXML spreadsheet (SpreadsheetML)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11116176/cell-styles-in-openxml-spreadsheet-spreadsheetml) as 劉鎮瑲 said, thanks 劉鎮瑲 and everyone who helped.

Repaired Records: Format from /xl/styles.xml part (Styles)

I don't get this issue.
I've generated a .xlsx spreadsheet in C# using the OpenXML SDK, but can't figure out how to get cell styles working. I've been studying files produced by Excel, and can't quite figure out how it's done.

```
m_objSpreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(FileName, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);
m_objWorkbookPart = m_objSpreadsheetDocument.AddWorkbookPart();
m_objWorkbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();

// Add a WorksheetPart to the WorkbookPart.
m_objWorksheetPart = m_objWorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
m_objWorksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());
m_objWorksheet = m_objWorksheetPart.Worksheet;

// Add Sheets to the Workbook.
Sheets sheets = m_objSpreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild<Sheets>(new Sheets());

// Append a new worksheet and associate it with the workbook.
Sheet sheet = new Sheet()
{
    Id = m_objSpreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(m_objWorksheetPart),
    SheetId = 1,
    Name = _sheetName
};
sheets.Append(sheet);

wStylePart = m_objSpreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorkbookStylesPart>();

m_objSheetData = m_objWorksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();
```

Comment: Could you be more specific? What/where is being repaired?

Comment: It's when you open the file in Excel it prompts you to repair the file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cell styles in OpenXML spreadsheet (SpreadsheetML)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11116176/cell-styles-in-openxml-spreadsheet-spreadsheetml)

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a `WorkbookStylesPart` without setting its `Stylesheet`. You either need to remove the line

```
wStylePart = m_objSpreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorkbookStylesPart>();
```

Or you can set its `StyleSheet` property:

```
var wStylePart = m_objSpreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorkbookStylesPart>();
wStylePart.Stylesheet = new Stylesheet();
```

**Edit**

You also need to call `Close` on the `SpreadsheetDocument`. You can either add a call to `m_objSpreadsheetDocument.Close();` at the bottom of your code or, preferably, you should wrap the call to `SpreadsheetDocument.Create` in a `using` statement.

The full code would then look like this:

```
using (var m_objSpreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(file, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
{
    var m_objWorkbookPart = m_objSpreadsheetDocument.AddWorkbookPart();
    m_objWorkbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();

    // Add a WorksheetPart to the WorkbookPart.
    var m_objWorksheetPart = m_objWorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
    m_objWorksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());
    var m_objWorksheet = m_objWorksheetPart.Worksheet;

    // Add Sheets to the Workbook.
    Sheets sheets = m_objSpreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild<Sheets>(new Sheets());

    // Append a new worksheet and associate it with the workbook.
    Sheet sheet = new Sheet()
    {
        Id = m_objSpreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(m_objWorksheetPart),
        SheetId = 1,
        Name = "Sheet 1"
    };
    sheets.Append(sheet);

    //either both of these lines are required or neither of them; you can't add the WorkbookStylesPart alone
    var wStylePart = m_objSpreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorkbookStylesPart>();
    wStylePart.Stylesheet = new Stylesheet();

    var m_objSheetData = m_objWorksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();
}
```

Comment: still not working,  Repaired Records: Cell information from /xl/worksheets/sheet.xml part           and   Repaired Records: Format from /xl/styles.xml part (Styles)

Comment: @MohdWaqar, please see my edit. That code works without issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i set the wrong height for the font. So this error shows whenever open the excel using microsoft excel.

```
font.setFontHeight((short)(11*20));
```

Multiply with 20 with actual value. This is found and solved after long time analysis.